# NaiveBaies не хочет обрабатывать русский текст

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, nlp, классификация

Пытаюсь подступиться к классификации русскоязычных текстов и т.п. Пытался скормить байесу файлик, который вручную закинул в корпус `nltk`. Но, не может он совладать с кодировкой `utf-8`, как ты его не проси. Файлик pos_neg.csv результат обработки корпуса функцией:

```
df.to_csv('D:\\pos_neg.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

, где `df` - Dataframe, в который я считал нужные столбцы из БД с корпусом.

Сам код:

```
import nltk
import random
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

random.shuffle(documents)

#print(documents[1])

all_words = []
for w in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)
#print(all_words.most_common(15))
word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]
def find_features(document):
    words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features
print((find_features(movie_reviews.words('pos/pos_neg.csv'))))
featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

training_set = featuresets[:1900]


testing_set = featuresets[1900:]
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
print("Classifier accuracy percent:",(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100)
classifier.show_most_informative_features(15)`
```

Ошибку выдает такую:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position
>   31: ordinal not in range(128)

За корпус низкий поклон [@Юлии Рубцовой](http://study.mokoron.com/)

Comment: Я правильно вас понимаю - вы разбили корпус с русскоязычными твитами (поле `ttext`) на N (число твитов) файлов и подменили оригинальные `.txt` файлы в директориях `movie_reviews/pos` и `movie_reviews/neg` на ваши собственные?

Comment: не совсем. из корпуса я взял только ttext, (из pos и neg), закинул их в dataframe, потом оттуда сохранил в csv файл и закинул его в movie_reviews/pos

Comment: Так не получится модель построить - у вас будет всего один позитивный «sample” и в нем будут все слова. Если хотите воспользоваться movie_reviews - придётся подготовить входные данные в таком же виде как у них

Comment: в таком же виде не получается хотя бы потому, что в txt файл из dataframe запихнуть я способа не нашел

Comment: Можно воспользоваться ‘df.apply’ , но медленный и в результате надо создать порядка 400K файлов - по числу твитов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я вообще не использовал NLTK - решил все сделать средствами `SciKit Learn`.

Получилось построить модель простой логистической регрессии с точностью предсказания 99.79% (модели тренировалась на 5% от оригинального набора данных)

Попробовал два классификатора - результаты:

```
Classificator             Score
-------------------       -------
LogisticRegression        0.99788
MultinomialNB             0.97998
```

Вот код:

```
# https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790609

# Corpus download: http://study.mokoron.com/
# positive: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnpq3z4bcnoktiv/positive.csv?dl=0
# negative: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6u59ljhhjdg6j0/negative.csv?dl=0
# join them together: type positive.csv negative.csv > pos_neg.csv

#cols = 'id tdate tmane ttext ttype trep tfav tstcount tfol tfrien listcount'.split()

from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline
from sklearn.externals import joblib


def fit_log_regression(X, y, **grid_kwargs):
    # pipe line: vectorize tweets (one hot encoding), LogisticRegression
    pipeline = Pipeline([
        ("vect", CountVectorizer()),
        ("LogRegr", LogisticRegression())])

    param_grid = dict(vect__min_df=[1,2,3],  # [2, 3, 5, 10]
                      #vect__ngram_range=[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)],
                      vect__ngram_range=[(1,1),(2,5)],
                      vect__analyzer=['word', 'char_wb'],
                      LogRegr__C=[1,5,10],  # [0.1, 1, 10, 100],
                      LogRegr__max_iter=[100, 200])

    # optimize hyperparameters, using [param_grid]
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, **grid_kwargs)
    grid_search.fit(X, y)
    return grid_search

def fit_multinomial_nb(X, y, **grid_kwargs):
    # pipe line: vectorize tweets (one hot encoding), MultinomialNB
    pipeline = Pipeline([
        ("vect", CountVectorizer()),
        ("MultinomNB", MultinomialNB())])

    param_grid = dict(vect__min_df=[2, 3, 5, 7],
                      vect__ngram_range=[(1,1),(2,5)],
                      vect__analyzer=['char_wb'],
                      MultinomNB__alpha=[0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5])
    # optimize hyperparameters, using [param_grid]
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, **grid_kwargs)
    grid_search.fit(X, y)
    return grid_search

def print_grid_results(grid_search):
    print('Best score {}'.format(grid_search.best_score_))
    print('-' * 70)
    print('Best estimator')
    print(grid_search.best_estimator_)
    print('*' * 70)
    print('Best parameters:')
    print('*' * 70)
    print(grid_search.best_params_)
    print('-' * 70)

def main(path):    
    # read data set into DF. Only the following columns: ['id','tdate','ttext','ttype']
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', header=None,
                     names=['id','tdate','ttext','ttype'],
                     usecols=[0,1,3,4])
    # Speed up: randomly select 5% of data
    # comment it out for better prediction performance
    df = df.sample(frac=0.1)
    grid_lr = fit_log_regression(df['ttext'], df['ttype'], cv=3, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)
    grid_nb = fit_multinomial_nb(df['ttext'], df['ttype'], cv=3, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)

    print_grid_results(grid_lr)
    print_grid_results(grid_nb)

    # persist trained models
    joblib.dump(grid_lr, 'grid_search_lr.pkl') 
    joblib.dump(grid_nb, 'grid_search_nb.pkl') 

    features = np.array(grid_lr.best_estimator_.named_steps['vect'].get_feature_names())
    coefs = pd.Series(grid_lr.best_estimator_.named_steps['LogRegr'].coef_.ravel(), features)
    print('top 20 positive features:')
    print(coefs.nlargest(20))
    print('-' * 70)
    print('top 20 negative features:')
    print(coefs.nsmallest(20))
    print('-' * 70)

    test = pd.DataFrame({
        'ttext':['Погода сегодня полная фигня, но настроение все равно отличное',
                 'Ну сходил я на этот фильм. Отзывы были нормальные, а оказалось - отстой!',
                 'StackOverflow рулит'
                ]
    })
    test['expected'] = [1, -1, 1]
    test['pred_lr'] = grid_lr.best_estimator_.predict(test['ttext'])
    test['pred_nb'] = grid_nb.best_estimator_.predict(test['ttext'])
    pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False
    print(test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(r'pos_neg.csv.gz')
```

Вывод:

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  27 out of  27 | elapsed:  4.1min finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  34 tasks      | elapsed:  2.9min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  72 out of  72 | elapsed:  5.2min finished
Fitting 3 folds for each of 9 candidates, totalling 27 fits
Fitting 3 folds for each of 24 candidates, totalling 72 fits
Best score 0.999147685525349
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Best estimator
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(2, 5), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        st...ty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False))])
**********************************************************************
Best parameters:
**********************************************************************
{'LogRegr__C': 5, 'LogRegr__max_iter': 100, 'vect__analyzer': 'char_wb', 'vect__min_df': 1, 'vect__ngram_range': (2, 5)}
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Best score 0.9912711241734019
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Best estimator
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=7,
        ngram_range=(2, 5), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
        tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)), ('MultinomNB', MultinomialNB(alpha=0.001, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True))])
**********************************************************************
Best parameters:
**********************************************************************
{'MultinomNB__alpha': 0.001, 'vect__analyzer': 'char_wb', 'vect__min_df': 7, 'vect__ngram_range': (2, 5)}
----------------------------------------------------------------------
top 20 positive features:
)        6.369444
:d       2.618676
d        1.947700
:d       1.910473
:*       1.734840
))       1.629485
:)       1.458892
*        1.366540
:*       1.214488
 :d      1.009269
((((     0.977603
(((((    0.931960
а)       0.861353
о)       0.858732
 )       0.826503
и)       0.780178
 :d      0.735334
ь)       0.720020
я)       0.716996
).       0.716503
dtype: float64
----------------------------------------------------------------------
top 20 negative features:
(      -7.997158
:(     -2.714882
((     -2.699196
o_o    -2.362963
_o     -2.021426
o_     -1.718344
:|     -1.590767
|      -1.473865
:|     -1.441303
 (     -1.208332
о_о    -0.985073
_о     -0.948251
о_     -0.945060
 :|    -0.933028
;(     -0.918989
о_о    -0.856339
 :|    -0.848942
-/     -0.840634
:-/    -0.840634
_о     -0.819273
dtype: float64
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                               ttext  expected  pred_lr  pred_nb
0  Погода сегодня полная фигня, но настроение все...         1        1       -1
1  Ну сходил я на этот фильм. Отзывы были нормаль...        -1       -1       -1
2                                StackOverflow рулит         1        1        1
```

Comment: [Вот CSV файл, который я использовал в ответе](https://ufile.io/i0lg8)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73779/discussion-between-lynx-and-maxu).

Comment: [на странице с корпусом](http://study.mokoron.com/) сказано: *"автоматически размеченных на два класса (положительные и отрицательные)."* Можно ли объяснить высокий? процент `99.79%` совпадения, тем что похожие методы для автоматической классификации использовались? (возможно, что даже если людей посадить классифицировать -- расхождение больше будет)¶ Куча  магических констант выглядят как ..магия :)

Comment: @jfs, скорее всего виной тому то, что модель "подглядывала" в тренировочную выборку)

Comment: @lynx, отвечаю на вопрос из правки моего ответа (вообще лучше вопросы задавать как вопросы или в комментариях) -  конечно можно, именно для этого я использовал `joblib.dump(...)` - сохранение натренированной модели в Pickle файл. Потом можно просто прочитать это следующим образом: `model = joblib.load(r'/path/to/file.pkl')`

Comment: @lynx: я не понял, что вы имели в виду. Если ответ на мой вопрос положительный, тогда польза от корпуса при использовании похожих методов не очень понятна (так как мы не знаем истинных значений (как люди текст понимают), а то что две программы использующие похожие алгоритмы похожие результаты выдают -- это не очень впечатляет).

Comment: @jfs, насколько я понимаю, MaxU  использовал и для тренировки и для тестов один и тот же РАЗМЕЧЕННЫЙ корпус (поправьте меня, если я не прав). поэтому система и выдала такую точность. если в качестве тестовых данных использовать другие данные, то точность получается вполне адекватная=)

Comment: @lynx: я не понимаю, что вы хотите сказать. Допустим, что ответ отрицательный на мой вопрос выше (плюсы/минусы расставлены адекватно в корпусе), тогда то что код, используя 5% корпуса, выдаёт результаты 99.79% совпадения на 100% корпуса, подсказало бы нам, что код рабочий и при использовании твитов не из корпуса -- мы можем высокий результат ожидать при сравнении с разметкой вручную¶ Может пример поможет: представьте алгоритм: вернуть 1 для любого ввода и мы составили "корпус", используя этот алгоритм. Тогда любой другой алгоритм, который 1 часто выдаёт будет часто совпадать с "корпусом"

Comment: @jfs, Да, я понимаю о чем вы(кажется=)). Тут дело еще в корпусе. он очень большой, + подобран так, что есть очень выразительные признаки: смайлы. По ним и классифицируется, у них очень большой вес. В последствии я буду пытаться вводить в этот алгоритм tf-idf, чтобы корректнее оценивать выборки, где нет или очень мало смайликов

Comment: @lynx, ваш вопрос и ваши с jfs комментарии побудили меня сделать [сравнение различных классификаторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792931/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA)