# Очень долгий прогон цикла в jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(1000000, 2)),columns=['a','b'])
df[['a','b']] = df[['a','b']].astype(str)

for i in range(2, df.shape[0]):
        df['b'][i] = df['a'][i-2] + ' ' + df['a'][i-1] + ' ' + df['a'][i] + ' ' + df['a'][i+1]
```

Очень долго крутит цикл. У меня есть датафрейм (1kk строк). Мне необходимо стринг-колонку "b" заполнить элементами из стринг-колонки "а", поэлементно. Такой прогон занимает очень много времени (30-60 минут). Как правильно использовать цикл в питоне?

Я часто сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой в jupyter. В моем случае даже простой цикл

```
for i in range(0,1000000):
    df['b'][i] = df['a'][i+1]
```

выполняется долго.

Решаемая задача:
У меня есть 30 слов. Предложения из этих слов записаны в колонку df['a'] в каждой ячейке по одному слову. Я хочу узнать распределения последовательности этих слов (по 4 слова в словосочетании), т.е. последовательность "мама" + "любит" + "сильно" + "машу" встречается гораздо меньше чем "мама" + "сильно" + "любит" + "машу" итд.

Собственно для решения этой задачи и создается df['b']

**Ответ**
 В jupitere действительно циклы медленно работают с dataFrame [ссылка] (https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6). Тут все ясно расписано как с ними нужно работать, но мне было лень разбираться. В итоге я запилил так

```
df['b'] = df.a.shift[2] + df.a.shift[1] + df.a + df.a.shift[-1]
```

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Пробовали "развернуть" цикл?

Comment: вы можете описать зачем вам это? есть подозрение, что вы пытаетесь реализовать скользящее окно, но тогла непонятно почему вы работаете со строками, а не с числами...

Comment: спасибо за уточнение! Вы можете привести более реальный набор данных (можно выложить на какой-нибудь) файлообменник. То что вы пытаетесь сделать уже реализовано в [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) - параметр `ngram_range`

Comment: В [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790796/211923) я как раз делал то же самое

Comment: Удалось выкрутиться без сторонних библиотек. Спасибо @MaxU

Comment: @NikolaiGerasimenyk, да, когда у вас 30 слов - этот подход может сработать... В той ссылке, что я дал обрабатывалось более 200.000 твитов, в каждом из которых много слов... ;-)