# Классификация русских текстов, определение тональности.Не совсем понятно назначение параметров классификатора

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, классификация, nlp

Вот код из ответа на [заданный ранее вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790609/naivebaies-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82):

```
# https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790609

# Corpus download: http://study.mokoron.com/
# positive: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnpq3z4bcnoktiv/positive.csv?dl=0
# negative: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6u59ljhhjdg6j0/negative.csv?dl=0
# join them together: type positive.csv negative.csv > pos_neg.csv

#cols = 'id tdate tmane ttext ttype trep tfav tstcount tfol tfrien listcount'.split()

from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline
from sklearn.externals import joblib


def fit_log_regression(X, y, **grid_kwargs):
    # pipe line: vectorize tweets (one hot encoding), LogisticRegression
    pipeline = Pipeline([
        ("vect", CountVectorizer()),
        ("LogRegr", LogisticRegression())])

    param_grid = dict(vect__min_df=[3, 5],  # [2, 3, 5, 10]
                      #vect__ngram_range=[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)],
                      vect__ngram_range=[(1,1),(2,5)],
                      vect__analyzer=['word', 'char_wb'],
                      LogRegr__C=[10, 100, 500],  # [0.1, 1, 10, 100],
                      LogRegr__max_iter=[100, 200])

    # optimize hyperparameters, using [param_grid]
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, **grid_kwargs)
    grid_search.fit(X, y)
    return grid_search

def fit_multinomial_nb(X, y, **grid_kwargs):
    # pipe line: vectorize tweets (one hot encoding), MultinomialNB
    pipeline = Pipeline([
        ("vect", CountVectorizer()),
        ("MultinomNB", MultinomialNB())])

    param_grid = dict(vect__min_df=[3, 5],
                      vect__ngram_range=[(1,1),(2,5)],
                      vect__analyzer=['word', 'char_wb'],
                      MultinomNB__alpha=[0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1.0])
    # optimize hyperparameters, using [param_grid]
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, **grid_kwargs)
    grid_search.fit(X, y)
    return grid_search

def print_grid_results(grid_search):
    print('Best score {}'.format(grid_search.best_score_))
    print('-' * 70)
    print('Best estimator')
    print(grid_search.best_estimator_)
    print('*' * 70)
    print('Best parameters:')
    print('*' * 70)
    print(grid_search.best_params_)
    print('-' * 70)

def main(path):    
    # read data set into DF. Only the following columns: ['id','tdate','ttext','ttype']
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', header=None,
                     names=['id','tdate','ttext','ttype'],
                     usecols=[0,1,3,4])
    # Speed up: randomly select 5% of data
    # comment it out for better prediction performance
    df = df.sample(frac=0.1)
    grid_lr = fit_log_regression(df['ttext'], df['ttype'], cv=3, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)
    grid_nb = fit_multinomial_nb(df['ttext'], df['ttype'], cv=3, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)

    print_grid_results(grid_lr)
    print_grid_results(grid_nb)

    # persist trained models
    joblib.dump(grid_lr, 'grid_search_lr.pkl') 
    joblib.dump(grid_nb, 'grid_search_nb.pkl') 

    features = np.array(grid_lr.best_estimator_.named_steps['vect'].get_feature_names())
    coefs = pd.Series(grid_lr.best_estimator_.named_steps['LogRegr'].coef_.ravel(), features)
    print('top 20 positive features:')
    print(coefs.nlargest(20))
    print('-' * 70)
    print('top 20 negative features:')
    print(coefs.nsmallest(20))
    print('-' * 70)

    test = pd.DataFrame({
        'ttext':['Погода сегодня полная фигня, но настроение все равно отличное',
                 'Ну сходил я на этот фильм. Отзывы были нормальные, а оказалось - отстой!',
                 'StackOverflow рулит'
                ]
    })
    test['expected'] = [1, -1, 1]
    test['pred_lr'] = grid_lr.best_estimator_.predict(test['ttext'])
    test['pred_nb'] = grid_nb.best_estimator_.predict(test['ttext'])
    pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False
    print(test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(r'pos_neg.csv.gz')
```

Вывод:

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  34 tasks      | elapsed:  1.5min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 144 out of 144 | elapsed:  7.1min finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  34 tasks      | elapsed:   37.6s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 120 out of 120 | elapsed:  2.4min finished
Fitting 3 folds for each of 48 candidates, totalling 144 fits
Fitting 3 folds for each of 40 candidates, totalling 120 fits
Best score 0.999030110655557
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Best estimator
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=3,
        ngram_range=(2, 5), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        st...ty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False))])
**********************************************************************
Best parameters:
**********************************************************************
{'LogRegr__C': 10, 'LogRegr__max_iter': 100, 'vect__analyzer': 'char_wb', 'vect__min_df': 3, 'vect__ngram_range': (2, 5)}
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Best score 0.9843935987303267
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Best estimator
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=5,
        ngram_range=(2, 5), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
        tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)), ('MultinomNB', MultinomialNB(alpha=0.01, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True))])
**********************************************************************
Best parameters:
**********************************************************************
{'MultinomNB__alpha': 0.01, 'vect__analyzer': 'char_wb', 'vect__min_df': 5, 'vect__ngram_range': (2, 5)}
----------------------------------------------------------------------
top 20 positive features:
)        6.615932
:d       2.652038
:d       2.011449
d        1.995172
:*       1.726206
))       1.631845
:)       1.618852
:*       1.362751
*        1.352714
((((     1.032752
 :d      1.018513
(((((    0.946603
а)       0.912792
 )       0.857700
о)       0.855670
 :d      0.776020
).       0.743704
ь)       0.743562
я)       0.718062
;)       0.690497
dtype: float64
----------------------------------------------------------------------
top 20 negative features:
(      -8.277490
((     -2.706023
:(     -2.454728
o_o    -2.329807
_o     -2.046104
o_     -1.830299
:|     -1.535142
|      -1.450972
:|     -1.417402
 (     -1.160076
;(     -0.902893
о_о    -0.871438
о_     -0.870233
о_о    -0.869731
_о     -0.861229
_о     -0.859388
-/     -0.847609
:-/    -0.847609
 :|    -0.831238
 :|    -0.831238
dtype: float64
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                               ttext  expected  pred_lr  pred_nb
0  Погода сегодня полная фигня, но настроение все...         1        1       -1
1  Ну сходил я на этот фильм. Отзывы были нормаль...        -1        1       -1
2                                StackOverflow рулит         1        1        1
```

Собственно, непонятно, почему заданы именно такие значения в param_grid, также не до конца ясно, за что отвечают эти параметры(каждый в отдельности)

Также, прошу знающих людей подсказать, нормально ли , что наиболее "влияющими" являются различные смайлики? Если нет, то как это фиксить? Мне в голову, кроме просто ручного удаления(в sublime text 2,например), ничего в голову не пришло

Также, появилась необходимость в качестве тестовых данных брать комментарии из БД..  Я это делаю так:

```
    db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='',
                        database='mom_db', charset='utf8')

    test = pd.read_sql("SELECT comm FROM comments ", db)


    test['comm'] = test['comm'].apply(delete_tabs)
    #test['expected'] = [-1, -1, 1, 1]
    test['pred_lr'] = grid_lr.best_estimator_.predict(test['comm'])
    test['pred_nb'] = grid_nb.best_estimator_.predict(test['comm'])
    pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False
    print(test)
```

где

```
def delete_tabs(str):
    str = str.lstrip()
    str = str.rstrip()
    return str
```

для того чтобы удалить лишние знаки табуляции, которые зачем-то были в классе с комментами на сайте.

Переобучил модель на корпусе в начальном виде(не удаляя смайлы и т.п.)...вот часть вывода:

```
top 20 positive features:
)        6.175323
:d       2.393173
d        2.010635
:d       1.867269
:*       1.654194
))       1.575834
:)       1.386353
:*       1.199153
*        1.188369
 :d      0.916147
(((((    0.886899
а)       0.832452
((((     0.828972
 )       0.718146
ь)       0.711038
 :d      0.708241
).       0.669910
о)       0.594219
е)       0.591869
:)       0.589400
dtype: float64
```

смущают "((((" и "(((((" как одни из наиболее "позитивных". Почему так может быть? корпус ведь размечен верно...

И еще. Как думаете, реально ил научить модель распознавать сарказм, иронию? Может быть есть идеи у кого-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробую ответить на некоторые вопросы:

1. такие значения в `param_grid` выбраны интуитивно и исходя из личного опыта автора ответа. Можно выбрать гораздо большую сетку параметров, но время работы GridSearchCV при этом резко вырастет.
2. по поводу параметров - [лучше смотреть в документации](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html)
3. смайлики и "эмодзи", **по-моему**, одна из самых значимых характеристик для тональной/эмоциональной характеристики постов в соц. сетях
4. обрабатывать текст можно напрямую в Pandas DataFrame - [заменами с использованием регулярных выражений](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html)

Comment: смайлики, конечно признак хороший, только вот как быть в ситуации, когда человек напишет в комментарии "все потому, что он "нехороший человек"!! ))" со смайликами в конце? коммент-то ведь отрицательный, но смайлик все потянет в "+"

Comment: да, кстати, сайт с которого я беру данные для анализа, к сожалению, использует смайлы-картинки. их я ведь не проанализирую никак?

Comment: @lynx, как эти картинки выглядят в вашем Data set? Как имена файлов или по-другому?

Comment: @МахU,при парсинге сайта их просто удаляют, но , по идее , можно и не удалять. а на сайте- вот так :'<img src="images/smilies/crazy.gif" border="0" alt="" title="Crazy" class="inlineimg">'

Comment: @lynx, ну вот вам и ответ. :) Если оставить только имя файла, то получится отличный признак. Скорее всего придётся заменить точку на подчеркивание, чтобы токенизатор не разбил имя файла...

Comment: @МахU, неужели имя файла и впрямь воспримется как единый, целостный признак?? тем более что в тренировочном корпусе нет таких признаков...

Comment: Я имел в виду- модель нужно будет натренировать на ваши имена файлов. Можно добавить записи с именами  файлов  в тренировочный корпус

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73878/discussion-between-lynx-and-maxu).

Comment: @lynx, я сейчас с телефона пишу- в чат написать не получается. Надо подумать , а лучше попробовать разные варианты. Я бы попробовал добавить строки , например удвоить корпус, заменив смайлики соответствующими им именами файлов в склонированной части корпуса