# Найти топ-N наиболее часто встречаемых слов в комментариях

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nltk

есть база данных с комментариями. необходимо найти топ самых частых во всех комментариях. Все, что на данный момент удалось сделать- находить кол-во встреч конкретного слова, которое непосредственно в коде задается. Можно ли как-то реализовать такой поиск, при том универсальный для любого набора комментариев/текстов/еще чего-то на русском языке?

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import pymysql
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import state_union
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

#подключаюсь к базе данных, записываю комментарии в DataFrame
db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='',
                      database='mom_db', charset='utf8')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT comm2 FROM comments ", db)


#Функция убирает лишние символы по границе текста,точки , запятые и проч.
def delete_chars(str):
    str = str.lstrip()
    str = str.rstrip()
    str = str.replace("."," ")
    str = str.replace(","," ")
    str = str.replace("-"," ")
    str = str.replace("?"," ")
    str = str.replace("!"," ")
    str = str.replace(")"," ")
    str = str.replace("("," ")
    str = str.replace("..."," ")
    str = str.replace("—"," ") 
    str = str.replace(":"," ")
    str = str.replace("<"," ")
    str = str.replace(">"," ")
    str = str.replace("/"," ")
    str = str.replace("``"," ")
    str = str.replace("'"," ")
    str = str.replace("«", " ")
    str = str.replace("»", " ")
    str = str.replace(";", " ")
    str = str.lower()
    return str



df['comm2'] = df['comm2'].apply(delete_chars)

st_w = set(stopwords.words('russian'))    
words_filtered = []  
i = 0
for df['comm2'][i] in df['comm2']: 
    df_tok = word_tokenize(df['comm2'][i]) 
    i = i + 1
    for w in df_tok:
        if w not in st_w:
            words_filtered.append(w)
print(words_filtered)

count = words_filtered.count('Европе')
print(count)
```

P.S. может есть более оптимальное решение вместо функции delete_chars?

пример необходимого вывода:

```
"слово_1" 33 
"слово_2" 22 
"слово_3" 11
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на функцию `plot_word_cloud()` из [данного ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793660/%d0%92%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%85%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85/793661#793661) я там делал практически тоже что и вы хотите сделать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize, FreqDist
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import string
import requests


def get_text(url, encoding='utf-8', to_lower=True):
    url = str(url)
    if url.startswith('http'):
        r = requests.get(url)
        if not r.ok:
            r.raise_for_status()
        return r.text.casefold() if to_lower else r.text
    elif os.path.exists(url):
        with open(url, encoding=encoding) as f:
            return f.read().casefold() if to_lower else f.read()
    else:
        raise Exception('parameter [url] must be either URL or a filename')


def mk_trans_tab(chars2remove):
    return str.maketrans(dict(zip(chars2remove, list(' ' * len(chars2remove)))))


# Гоголь Н. В. "Ревизор" ( http://lifeinbooks.net/chto-pochitat/nikolaj-gogol-revizor-vot-tak-i-po-sej-den/ )
url = r'C:\download\Gogol_N._Revizor.txt'

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('russian'))    
transl_tab = mk_trans_tab(list(string.punctuation) + list('\r\n«»\–'))


text = get_text(url, encoding='cp1251')

df = pd.DataFrame({'comm':re.split(r'[\n\r\.\?!]', text)})
df['comm'] = df['comm'].str.translate(transl_tab).str.lower()

words = [w for w in word_tokenize(df['comm'].str.cat(sep=' ')) if w not in stop_words]

fdist = FreqDist(words)

print(fdist.most_common(20))
```

Вывод:

```
[('хлестаков', 244),
 ('городничий', 193),
 ('это', 155),
 ('анна', 127),
 ('андреевна', 125),
 ('осип', 78),
 ('марья', 65),
 ('антоновна', 64),
 ('добчинский', 63),
 ('аммос', 60),
 ('говорит', 60),
 ('федорович', 59),
 ('артемий', 58),
 ('филиппович', 58),
 ('бобчинский', 58),
 ('почтмейстер', 55),
 ('очень', 51),
 ('явление', 51),
 ('тебе', 50),
 ('иванович', 42)]
```

Comment: для сравнения без учёта регистра лучше [casefold() вместо lower() использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551443/4279).

Comment: @jfs, согласен. К сожалению в Pandas этот метод не реализован...

Answer (score 1):

Может быть кому-то пригодиться и моя кривоватая реализация)) + прикрутил сюда еще приведение слов к нормальной(начальной) форме

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import pymysql
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import state_union
from nltk import word_tokenize, FreqDist
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
import pymorphy2
#подключаюсь к базе данных, записываю комментарии в DataFrame
db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='',
                      database='mom_db', charset='utf8')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT comm2 FROM comments ", db)


#Функция убирает лишние символы по границе текста,точки , запятые и проч.
def mk_trans_tab(chars2remove):
    return str.maketrans(dict(zip(chars2remove, list(' ' * len(chars2remove)))))

transl_tab = mk_trans_tab(list(string.punctuation) + list('\r\n«»\–'))
df['comm2'] = df['comm2'].str.translate(transl_tab).str.lower()


st_w = set(stopwords.words('russian'))    
words_filtered = []  
i = 0
for df['comm2'][i] in df['comm2']: 
    df_tok = word_tokenize(df['comm2'][i]) 
    i = i + 1
    for w in df_tok:
        if w not in st_w:
            parsed_words = morph.parse(w)[0]
            normalized_words = parsed_words.normal_form
            words_filtered.append(normalized_words)

count = FreqDist(words_filtered)
print(count.most_common(20))
```

вывод получил такой (что лично меня вполне устроило):

```
[('газ', 111), ('россия', 110), ('европа', 97), ('газа', 87), ('украина', 70), ('газпром', 66), ('цена', 60), ('страна', 49), ('российский', 45), ('бюджет', 41), ('покупать', 37), ('сша', 33), ('ввп', 33), ('ес', 31), ('доход', 31), ('какой', 30), ('рф', 30), ('деньга', 28), ('2', 28), ('нефть', 25)]
```