# Работа со строкой (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, текст

У меня есть программа, которая находит 10 самых популярных символов в строке.

```
text = input()
words = {}
spisok = []
def find():
    global words
    max = 0
    h = False
    mean = ''
    for key in words:
        if words[key] > max:
            max = words[key]
            mean = key
            h = True
    if not h:
        return False
    else:
        return mean
text = text.strip("\t\n")
for word in text:
    if word not in words:
        words[word] = 1
    else:
        words[word] += 1
for g in range(10):
    give = find()
    if not give:
        break
    else:
        spisok.append(give)
        del words[give]
end = ' '.join(spisok)
print(end)
```

Но проблема в том,что в мою программу подаётся строка, которая содержит специальные символы (\n, \t и т.д.). Как мне сделать так,чтобы программа читала строку целиком ,и эти символы не мешали этом. Например как здесь:

```
ВОЙНА И МИР
ТОМ ПЕРВЫЙ
ЧАСТЬ ПЕРВАЯ
I
— Eh bien, mon prince. Gênes et Lucques ne sont plus que des apanages, des поместья, de la famille Buonaparte. Non, je vous préviens que si vous ne me dites pas que nous avons la guerre, si vous vous permettez encore de pallier toutes les infamies, toutes les atrocités de cet Antichrist (ma parole, j'y crois) — je ne vous connais plus, vous n'êtes plus mon ami, vous n'êtes plus мой верный раб, comme vous dites 1. Ну, здравствуйте, здравствуйте. Je vois que je vous fais peur 2, садитесь и рассказывайте.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518 первый ответ - оно?

Comment: Нет, мне не нужно удалять пробелы или другую пунктуацию.

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793660/%d0%92%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%85%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85)

Answer (score 4):

Действия:

- Разбиваем текст на слова (используем регулярные выражения, [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.findall))
- Подсчитываем слова (используем [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter))

Код:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

text = """\
ВОЙНА И МИР
ТОМ ПЕРВЫЙ
ЧАСТЬ ПЕРВАЯ
I
— Eh bien, mon prince. Gênes et Lucques ne sont plus que des apanages, des поместья, de la famille Buonaparte. Non, je vous préviens que si vous ne me dites pas que nous avons la guerre, si vous vous permettez encore de pallier toutes les infamies, toutes les atrocités de cet Antichrist (ma parole, j'y crois) — je ne vous connais plus, vous n'êtes plus mon ami, vous n'êtes plus мой верный раб, comme vous dites 1. Ну, здравствуйте, здравствуйте. Je vois que je vous fais peur 2, садитесь и рассказывайте.
"""

words = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text.lower())
print(words)  # ['война', 'и', 'мир', 'том', 'первый', 'часть', 'первая', 'i', ...

counter = Counter(words)  # Counter({'vous': 9, 'plus': 4, 'que': 4, 'je': 4, 'ne': 3, ...
print(counter)

# Получаем топ-10 слов
counter_top10 = counter.most_common(10)
print(counter_top10)  # [('vous', 9), ('plus', 4), ('que', 4), ('je', 4), ('ne', 3),

words_top10 = [word for word, _ in counter_top10]
print(words_top10)  # ['vous', 'plus', 'que', 'je', 'ne', 'de', 'и', 'mon', 'des', 'la']
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь можно использовать split:`text = text.split(' ')`
Это вернёт отдельные слова. `['ВОЙНА','И','МИР']`
Чтобы избавиться от символов нужно будет завести отдельный их список к примеру:

```
p=[',', '!', '?', ':', '\n']
if p in text:
            text.pop(p)
```

Или так:

```
import re
text=text.readlines()
for i in text:
    text=re.sub(r'\W+', ' ' , i.lower()).split(' ')
```