# Ошибка при обучении LogisticRegression

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, машинное-обучение

Строка в коде на кот.ошибка:

```
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Текст ошибки:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'K01'

Как правильно обработать входные данные для обучения, что бы при конвертации не возникало проблем ?

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: Добрый день MaxU. Не могу привести пример, так как этот символ печатается и показывается как нормальный нул. Могу со скринить

Comment: По-моему проблема в букве “K”, которую вы хотите преобразовать в число

Comment: Нет. Был атрибут с аналогичной проблемой. В том атрибуте было слово "ДИРЕКТОР" и буква '0' была тоже с диагональю. См атрибут я удалил, ну вот при последующей обработке эта проблема с 0 появляется с нова. Скрин отправил .

Comment: В некоторых шрифтах ноль сделан с диагональю, чтобы не путать с буквами “o”, “O”

Comment: Текст ошибки вполне понятен - невозможно преобразовать строку “K01” в целое число.

Comment: Тогда, вопрос как заменить 'o' диагональю на обычную О

Comment: вы правы. В слове директор нормальное О. Как тогда запретить переводить стринг атрибуты в интеджер. Поскольку INFO говорит что все поля интеджер.

Comment: Что выводит “print(0)” в вашей среде? Ноль с диагональю

Comment: нет. нормальный о.

Comment: Без воспроизводимого примера - это беспредметный разговор :(

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ЗАМЕСТИТЕЛЬ ДИРЕКТОРА'

Comment: Вам нужен пример кода ?

Comment: Да зачем? Мы тут все мастера угадывания и телепатии (сарказм)

Comment: Я понимаю ваше ситуацию. Поймите и вы мою. Я не могу более подробно описать эту проблему так всё что у меня есть это код ошибки. Бесконечно удалять атрибуты тоже не выход.

Comment: Если вы заинтересованы в ответе, а не в бесконечном “пинг-понге” в комментах, то я вам настойчиво рекомендую прочитать как следует задавать вопросы на SO: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и __воспроизводимый__ пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: и [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-pandas-numpy-scipy-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Практически все алгоритмы классификации и регрессии ожидают на входе числовую (с целыми или вещественными числами) матрицу. Некоторые методы, заметив что тип данных не числовой, пытаются преобразовать все элементы в вещественное число (`float`). Это сработает если все значения - числа представленные в виде строк.

Пример:

```
In [1]: a = np.array(["123", "456", "-789"])

In [2]: a
Out[2]: array(['123', '456', '-789'], dtype='<U4')

In [3]: a = np.array(a, dtype='float')

In [4]: a
Out[4]: array([ 123.,  456., -789.])
```

Ваш случай:

```
In [11]: a = np.array(['K01', 'ЗАМЕСТИТЕЛЬ ДИРЕКТОРА'])

In [12]: a
Out[12]: array(['K01', 'ЗАМЕСТИТЕЛЬ ДИРЕКТОРА'], dtype='<U21')

In [13]: a = np.array(a, dtype='float')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-ac40b9268d6f> in <module>()
----> 1 a = np.array(a, dtype='float')

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'K01'
```

Вывод: вам надо преобразовать строки в числа. Для этого есть несколько подходов, применение которых, выбирают в зависимости от поставленной задачи.

Наиболее распространенным методом является метод "one-hot-encoding" векторизации.

Пример:

```
In [14]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [15]: vect = CountVectorizer()

In [16]: data = ['LogisticRegression returns the following error:',
                 'ValueError: "could not convert string to float"']

In [17]: X = vect.fit_transform(data)

In [18]: X
Out[18]:
<2x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 12 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [19]: X.A
Out[19]:
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)

In [20]: pd.SparseDataFrame(X, columns=vect.get_feature_names(), default_fill_value=0)
Out[20]:
   convert  could  error  float  following  logisticregression  not  returns  string  the  to  valueerror
0        0      0      1      0          1                   1    0        1       0    1   0           0
1        1      1      0      1          0                   0    1        0       1    0   1           1
```

Comment: Преобразование: категориальных данных 
 df=pd.get_dummies(df)

Comment: @максимильин, можно и так, но `CountVectorizer` предоставляет гораздо больше возможностей...

Comment: @максимильин, возможно вам будет интересно посмотреть на примеры из [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792931/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA)