# Отладка скрипта на Python по вызову модели ML из командной строки

Tags: python, cmd, машинное-обучение

Задача скрипта подтягивающего модель машинного обучения, приведенного в листинге ниже - принимать на вход из командной строки аргументы.

Сам скрипт:

```
import sys
import argparse
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import pickle
import re
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    columnsList = ['OGRN',
                   'cases_0_sum',
                   'cases_1_sum',
                   'cases_2_sum',
                   'cases_3_sum',
                   'cases_4_sum',
                   'cases_5_sum',
                   'cases_6_sum',
                   'cases_7_sum',
                   'cases_8_sum',
                   'cases_9_sum',
                   'blocks_0_count'
                   'blocks_0_sum',
                   'Balance_values_12003',
                   'Balance_values_12004',
                   'Balance_values_12303',
                   'Balance_values_12304',
                   'Balance_values_13103',
                   'Balance_values_14003',
                   'Balance_values_15003',
                   'Balance_values_15203',
                   'profit_class',
                   'executions_0_sum',
                   'executions_1_sum']
    df_in = pd.DataFrame([sys.argv[1:]], index=columnsList).T


    df_in[['num_successful_executions','num_successful_executions_sum']] = df_in['executions_0_sum'].str.split('\s*на сумму\s*', expand=True)
    df_in.drop(columns='executions_0_sum', inplace=True)


    df_in[['num_continuing_executions','num_continuing_executions_sum']] = df_in['executions_1_sum'].str.split('\s*на сумму\s*', expand=True)
    df_in.drop(columns='executions_1_sum', inplace=True)

    df_in['num_continuing_executions'].fillna('0', inplace=True)
    df_in['num_successful_executions'].fillna('0', inplace=True)
    df_in['num_continuing_executions']=pd.to_numeric(df_in['num_continuing_executions'],errors='coerce')
    df_in['num_successful_executions']=pd.to_numeric(df_in['num_successful_executions'],errors='coerce')
    df_in['num_continuing_executions'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df_in['num_successful_executions'].fillna(0, inplace=True)               


    for n in ['num_continuing_executions_sum','num_successful_executions_sum']:
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace('руб', '')
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace('млн', '00000')
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace('млрд', '00000000')
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace('Нет', '0')
        df_in[n].fillna('0', inplace=True)
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace('.', '')
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace(',', '')
        df_in[n]=df_in[n].str.replace(' ', '')
        df_in[n]=pd.to_numeric(df_in[n], errors='coerce')

    for n in df_in.columns:
        df_in[n]=pd.to_numeric(df_in[n], errors='coerce') 

    df_in['OGRN'] = df_in['OGRN'].map(lambda x: str(x)[3:5])
    df_in['OGRN']=pd.to_numeric(df_in['OGRN'])

    for n in [ 'Balance_values_12003',
                   'Balance_values_12004',
                   'Balance_values_12303',
                   'Balance_values_12304',
                   'Balance_values_13103',
                   'Balance_values_14003',
                   'Balance_values_15003',
                   'Balance_values_15203']:
        df_in[n+'_no_data_flag']=np.where(df_in[n]==np.nan,1,0)



    # load the model from disk
    filename1 = 'D:\knn.pickle'
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename1, 'rb'))
    y2_pred = loaded_model.predict(df_in)


    wished_sum =float(input())
    prob = 95*float(y2_pred)/float(wished_sum)
    if prob>=95:
        prob = 95
    print("{:.1f} ".format(y2_pred),'\n',wished_sum, '{:.1f} %'.format(prob))
```

Аргументы на вход: `107705 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 150000 120000 100000 90000 10000 200000 200000 170000 -1 "80 на сумму 939 836 руб." "3 на сумму 252 500 руб."` что соответствует входу (24 аргумента) и модели.

Однако скрипт выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\1\Execution_prediction.py", line 94, in <module>
    y2_pred = loaded_model.predict(df_in)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\regression.py", line 142, in predict
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 453, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 44, in _assert_all_finite
    " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

В чем смысл такой ошибки, когда обученная без проблем модель получает на ввод ровно столько сколько нужно?

Comment: можете выложить `knn.pickle` чтобы можно было воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JpDv87_WXj3bCfANqGgfnjdXNhZFmNI1

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Отладка была на винде 10, если что

Comment: у меня ваш код вываливается на `df_in[['num_successful_executions','num_successful_executions_sum']] = df_in['executions_0_sum'].str.split('\s*на сумму\s*', expand=True)` с ошибкой `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uNM5Oxi5VckNeNn3Z0UGR9IN-eaGzCZz

Удалось кое-что понять: на вход в модель данные поступают не так, как вводятся. Только первое значение обрабатывается и попадает как надо, остальные пропадают и заменяются ерундой. По ссылке, актуальный скрипт, пикл и скрин командной строки

Comment: Один только маленький вопрос остался - как прописать адрес пикловского объекта на участке `filename1 = 'D:\knn.pickle'
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename1, 'rb')) ` чтобы он читался из любой папки где находится сам скрипт?

Comment: я это делал [так (поищите в коде `__file__`)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/792932/211923)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ключевая ошибка была здесь `df_in = pd.DataFrame([sys.argv[1:]], index=columnsList).T`
Правильный код: `df_in = pd.DataFrame(sys.argv[1:], index=columnsList).T` ввод аргументов без дополнительных квадратных скобок. Отсюда поехало все форматирование. Остальные баги ловятся классическим построчным раскомментированием.

Comment: о, а я как раз собирался посмотреть... Здорово, что вы сами нашли проблему)

Comment: Расту понемногу, как прогер)