# Как автоматизировать классифицирование текста?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, классификация-текста

Имеется список обращений, каждый из которых представляет собой осмысленный текст. Каждому обращению необходимо задать маркер (тег), классифицировать: жалоба, похвала, ругательство и так далее.

Сейчас это все делается вручную. Хотелось бы автоматизировать этот процесс. Полагаю, что возможно это сделать с помощью машинного обучения.

Может кто-то из присутствующих сталкивался с такой или похожей задачей?

Comment: А почему бы не искать в обращении определенные слова и по ним определять суть?

Comment: Вы или примите какой-то ответ, или спросите, если что-то непонятно или какой-то информации не хватает.

Answer (score 3):

Ну у вас же часть данных уже размечена, я так понимаю? То есть есть на чём попробовать "обучение с учителем". На первый прикид даже "мешок слов" подойдёт, то есть `CountVectorizer`. Дальше надо пробовать `TF-IDF`, а потом уже всякие эмбеддинги `Word2vec`. Для текстов, кстати, быстрые и простые вероятностные модели вроде `MultinomialNB` неплохо работают.

Главное сделать некоторый бейзлайн, а потом его можно улучшать:

- чистить мусорные слова/символы
- пробовать разные варианты токенизации: отдельные слова/сочетания слов, стемминг/лемматизация, приводить всё в один регистр или не нужно
- пробовать разные варианты векторизации подготовленных текстов: мешок слов, `tf-idf`, `word2vec`, `doc2vec`, `fasttext`
- пробовать разные модели, на ваших данных может взлететь разное, как минимум надо пробовать байесовские модели, деревянные модели, бустинги, нейросети; если данных много, то что-то из моделей может не пролезть по времени/памяти, так что процесс творческий

Там ещё есть разные тонкости. Если не знаете вообще как начать, я поищу ссылки, но можно погуглить text classification, наверняка вылезет много примеров, в частности на каггле.

Answer (score 3):

Да, это классическая задача машинного обучения. И как для почти всех задач машинного обучения, решающую роль играет качество данных, поданных на вход модели классификатору.

Какие данные вам понадобятся для обучения и проверки модели:

1. список обращений
2. заранее проставленный экспертом **вручную** тег

Далее делается предобработка текста. Практически все известные мне модели машинного обучения требуют на вход **числовые** матрицы. Соответственно сначала нужно будет получить такие матрицы. Конкретные детали векторизации текста будут зависеть от выбранного алгоритма классификации.

PS [здесь можно посмотреть примеры использования различных алгоритмов классификации текстов для определения эмоциональной оценки комментариев.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/792931/211923)

Comment: О, хорошая ссылка, надо посмотреть. А скорость там не мерили? А то у разных моделей скорость может на порядки отличаться, например наив байес может моментально работать, а SVM-ы по жизни дико тупят, стоит им скормить сколько-нибудь большие данные.

Comment: @CrazyElf, к сожалению не сохранил замеры. А так да, запомнил только SVC, который был в несколько раз медленнее всех остальных классификаторов :)

Comment: Ну, у меня вообще сложилось впечатление, что `SVM`-ы - это прошлый век и толку от них нет почти никогда. Да, им по-прежнему учат на курсах, потому что это понятная модель, но она тормозная и не шибко полезная по моему опыту на фоне современных ансамблей