# Перебор параметров GridSearchCV в sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Хочу создать pipeline с перебором параметров модели

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, Lasso
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

Пишу код

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', RobustScaler()),
    ('ridge', Ridge())
])

params = {
    'estimator__ridge__alpha': [x/100 for x in range(100)]
}

CV = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=params, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
CV.fit(train.values, y_train)
```

Выдаёт ошибку

```
Invalid parameter estimator for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('scaler', RobustScaler(copy=True, quantile_range=(25.0, 75.0), with_centering=True,
       with_scaling=True)), ('ridge', Ridge(alpha=1.0, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
   normalize=False, random_state=None, solver='auto', tol=0.001))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()
```

Ознакомился с похожими материалами [тут](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13410/parameters-in-gridsearchcv-in-scikit-learn?rq=1), [тут](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29410/how-to-set-parameters-to-search-in-scikit-learn-gridsearchcv) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899132/invalid-parameter-for-sklearn-estimator-pipeline)

```
for param in CV.get_params().keys():
    print(param)
```

Проверил параметры, скопировал соответственно *estimator__ridge__alpha*

```
cv
error_score
estimator__memory
estimator__steps
estimator__scaler
estimator__ridge
estimator__scaler__copy
estimator__scaler__quantile_range
estimator__scaler__with_centering
estimator__scaler__with_scaling
estimator__ridge__alpha
estimator__ridge__copy_X
estimator__ridge__fit_intercept
estimator__ridge__max_iter
estimator__ridge__normalize
estimator__ridge__random_state
estimator__ridge__solver
estimator__ridge__tol
estimator
fit_params
iid
n_jobs
param_grid
pre_dispatch
refit
return_train_score
scoring
verbose
```

Все равно выдаёт ошибку, подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя параметра должно соответствовать тому как вы назвали соответствующий шаг в `pipeline` - `<pipeline_step_name>__<parameter_name>`.

В вашем случае:

```
params = {
    'ridge__alpha': [x/100 for x in range(100)]
}
```

[В этом ответе я использовал тот же подход...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790796/211923)

Comment: Спасибо! То есть получается эта конструкция бессмысленна?
    for param in CV.get_params().keys():
        print(param)

Comment: нет, просто надо учитывать что `get_params()` добавляет `estimator__` в качестве префикса...